# Strange behavior of AutoCompleteTextView on Galaxy Note

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, galaxy

My customer reported an issue:

When he opens an activity of my App an AutoCompleteTextView which has focus (and is enabled) remains grey and insensitive for entering text via soft keyboard. After switching focus to and from another EditText the first AutoCompleteTextView becomes sensitive and accepts entered text.

The issue so far was reported only from Galaxy Note with Android 2.3.5.
Did anyone experience a similar problem?

Thank you.